# Dismissing UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a custom UITableView Cell

```
@interface PickTypeCell : UITableViewCell  <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtTextField;
@property (readwrite, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView* dtpPicker;

@end
```

The implementation file looks like

```
@implementation PickTypeCell

@synthesize txtTextField;
@synthesize dtpPicker;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"inside PickTypeCell init");

    //assign this to the picker delegate / datasource
    dtpPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    dtpPicker.dataSource = self;
    dtpPicker.delegate = self;

    // assign the picker to the text field input view,so the picker is displayed when the text field receives input event
    txtTextField.inputView=dtpPicker;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //retuns the number of columns of the picker view : 1
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //return the number of rows for each component : the number of tree types
    return 5;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //called to get the text to be displayed on each row of the picker
    return @"HAHAH";
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //called when the user clicks on a row of the picker view
    txtTextField.text=@"HABOOOOUN";
}
```

When the cell is loaded, the input text field is displayed.
When clicking on the text field, the picker view is displayed with 5 lines containing "HAHAH", as expected.
When clicking a line, the text in the text field is updated with the "HABOOOOUN" string.

But the picker is still displayed and I don't know how to dismiss it.

I'd like the picker to be dismissed when the user clicks any line in the picker.
If the user clicks on the text field again, the picker shall be displayed again.

I tried using [dtpPicker resignFirstResponder] in the "didSelectRow" method, without any success. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try resign the `UItextField` `[txtTextField resignFirstResponder]`

Comment: thanks I was so sure that it was on the picker that I should do something .... that I forgot to try on the txt field.

Answer (score 0):

```
PickTypeCell *cell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.txtTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

If you tap on textField or send message `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` textField became first responder and keyboard automatically appear. If you want to hide keyboard you should call `[textField resignFirstResponder];` You can change keyboard to other view `textField.inputView = myView;` what you already done